# Identification of a 12 V Quick-connect disconnect

Tags: identification, connector, automotive, wire-terminals

I am looking for help in identifying a specific type of Quick-connect disconnect:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

It's used in the context of 12 V vehicle or boating electronics (think 12 V "cigarette lighter" outlets, [USB chargers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09YTWNCM2) (my use case)) and has the nice feature that it has a locking pin which mates with the 12 V battery terminals, making the connection presumably rather vibration tolerant.

Markings that I could identify are "ZT" on the removable insulation piece and "JEP 2" on the backside of the cable isolation crimp.

Any tips as to sources or the proper term for the "locking pin" in order to google for it are highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Positive locking" quick-connect disconnects are used in consumer appliances as well as in automotive.

Search: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22positive+lock%22+quick-connect+faston

Here are some from TE: https://www.digikey.com/short/fpf5q58w

[image: TE 179974-1]

{Digikey}

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a common "Faston(tm)" 1/4 inch tab connector.  That type of connector is available with or without insulation and with different types of crimp connections for attaching to a wire.

Comment: Hi @peter,  thanks for the fast reply with the brand name "Faston". I found https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/brands/faston.html and will browse their product catalogues - maybe I can find the "locking" version I am looking for :)

Comment: Careful there: "Faston" is a brand name, and I suspect that the design with a "positive lock" wasn't theirs. A bot of Googling suggest that Neutrik do them e.g. https://www.rapidonline.com/neutrik-positive-lock-faston-4-8-x-0-5mm-pack-of-20-20-0872 I'm sure that I don't have to remind OP that selection of a high-quality connector will be undermined if he doesn't use a similarly high-quality crimping tool.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about using proper crimping equippment, @mark. I am planning on using a Knipex 97 49 05 which I believe to being the correct die for this type of F-crimp. (https://www.knipex.com/search?keys=97+49+05)